# Is this a safe way for inserting and updating an array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following code updates an array of specified objects or insert if the object is not in the database. It works fine but I'm new in mongodb and I'm not sure if this is a safe or fast way to do it.

Maybe I should use [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)? I tried to use it but I couldn't get the same behaviour as the following code.

```
mongodb.connect(mongo_url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else {
        var mongo_products_collection = db.collection("products")

        mongoUpsert(mongo_products_collection, data_products, function() {
            db.close()
        })
    }
})

function mongoUpsert(collection, data_array, cb) {
    var data_length = data_array.length

    for (var i=0; i < data_length; i++) {
        collection.update(
            {product_id: data_array[i].product_id},
            data_array[i],
            {upsert: true}
        )
    }

    return cb(false)
}
```

Comment: if you go inside a loop implies you are blocking the code and waiting for the loop to finish its functioning and then carry forward further, this is not the best practice as the loop may slow down the process adversely, i better recommend you mongoose query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the **[`bulkWrite`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite)** API to carry out the updates handles this better

```
mongodb.connect(mongo_url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else {
        var mongo_products_collection = db.collection("products")

        mongoUpsert(mongo_products_collection, data_products, function() {
            db.close()
        })
    }
})

function mongoUpsert(collection, data_array, cb) {

    var bulkUpdateOps = data_array.map(function(data) {
        return {
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": { 
                    "product_id": data.product_id,
                    "post_modified": { "$ne": data.post_modified }
                },
                "update": { "$set": data },
                "upsert": true
            }
        };
    });

    collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps, function(err, r) {
        // do something with result
    });

    return cb(false);
}
```

---

If you're dealing with larger arrays i.e. > 1000 then consider sending the writes to the server in batches of 500 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 500 requests.

For bulk operations MongoDB imposes a [default internal limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) of 1000 operations per batch and so the choice of 500 documents is good in the sense that you have some control over the batch size rather than let MongoDB impose the default, i.e. for larger operations in the magnitude of > 1000 documents. So for the above case in the first approach one could just write all the array at once as this is small but the 500 choice is for larger arrays.

```
var ops = [],
    counter = 0;

data_array.forEach(function(data) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { 
                "product_id": data.product_id, 
                "post_modified": { "$ne": data.post_modified } 
            },
            "update": { "$set": data },
            "upsert": true
        }
    });
    counter++;

    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        collection.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, r) {
            // do something with result
        });
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (counter % 500 != 0) {
    collection.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, r) {
        // do something with result
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that it's updating objects that didn't change, every object also has an post_modified variable, for example:

data_array[0].post_modified

So when I update an existing object how I can ignore it if post_modified it's the same?

Comment: @user3561335 Add in your filter the condition `"post_modified": { "$ne": data.post_modified }`, as in the updated answer.