# Performant bulk-update of many unique documents with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have many (>20k) documents like the following

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "data": "1"
}

{
  "id": 2,
  "data": "2"
}

...
```

and I wanted to update them to be like

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "data": "3"
}

{
  "id": 2,
  "data": "4"
}

...
```

Due to the sheer number of documents, doing a one-by-one update is simply not feasible in a reasonable amount of time. Because of this, I feel like it must be possible to bulk-update all the documents at once, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly. Attempting to search Google hasn't turned up any useful answers.

Edit: I know that updateMany() exists, my problem is that I'm not sure how to write an appropriate filter. For example:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "data": "1"
}

{
  "id": 2,
  "data": "2"
}
```

I want ONLY document id `1` to have `data` set to `"3"`, and ONLY document id `2` to have `data` set to `"4"`. From reading the updateMany() docs, I'm not sure how to do this.

Edit 2:

The objects in questions are [Discord guild entities](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-object). After stripping some of the extra data, what gets inserted looks like

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a80a877a2b51be70f2c3e72"), 
  "id" : NumberLong("123123123123123123"), 
  "afk_channel_id" : null, 
  "afk_timeout" : 300, 
  "application_id" : null, 
  "default_message_notifications" : 0, 
  "explicit_content_filter" : 0, 
  "features" : [ ], 
  "icon" : null, 
  "joined_at" : "<timestamp>", 
  "large" : false, 
  "member_count" : 2, 
  "mfa_level" : 0, 
  "name" : "Test", 
  "owner_id" : NumberLong("123123123123123123"), 
  "region" : "us-east", 
  "splash" : null, 
  "system_channel_id" : NumberLong("123123123123123123"), 
  "unavailable" : false, 
  "verification_level" : 0
}
```

and as such the most I've been able to query on *uniquely* has been the `id` field.

Comment: See [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany).

Comment: @JeffMatthews Please see the edit to the question.

Comment: Are you saying you want to add 2 to the value of data for every record?  What exactly is your pattern?

Comment: @JeffMatthews This is just an example. My real use-case has many documents with VERY different data, and the only real "filter-able" field is the `id` field. As such, I have no idea how to effectively bulk-update them.

Comment: Is there a pattern?  If you are saying it's all random values, then, no, I don't think so.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997511/is-this-a-safe-way-for-inserting-and-updating-an-array-of-objects-in-mongodb

Comment: @JeffMatthews The only "pattern" that I'm aware of is that all `id` fields are guaranteed unique :/ Outside of that, no.

Comment: Not looking good.  You might try editing your question to be more specific with the details on what the old and new values really look like.  Maybe someone can spot a pattern.

Comment: @JeffMatthews Has been updated with more specific information about what the data actually is.